# Laravel 5.2 paginating

Tags: php, html, laravel, view, pagination

I used this way to make a pagination for my site, but I still get an error!  I tried to solve and I searched a lot, didn't find a solution. I hope you can help me.

Controller -

```
class ContentController extends MasterController {


    public function content() {
$content = content::all()->paginate(10);  
$content->setPath('content'); //Customise Page Url
return view('content.boot',compact('content'));

}
}
```

view -

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')

@if(count($content) > 0 )

@foreach($content as $row)

<video width="330" controls>
    <source src="{{ asset('videos/' . $row['video'] )}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
@endforeach
@endif

{!! $content->render() !!} 

@endsection
```

route -

```
Route::get('/', 'ContentController@content');
```

Error -

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
>       Method paginate does not exist.

Answer (score 15):

remove all() function, your code should be:

```
$content = content::paginate(10);
```

Comment: thanks a lot , helped me , 
but now it appears behind the videos its sticky lets say , how can I make it in the bottom ? thanks

Answer (score 7):

As suggested by Gouda Elalfy you should remove the call to `all()`.

#### Explanation

The method `paginate()` is available on [`Eloquent\Builder`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate) which is what you implicitly have when you call `content::paginage(10)`.

However [`content::all()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all) returns a `Collection` or an array of `Model`, not a `Builder`.

Comment: thanks a lot , helped me , 
but now it appears behind the videos its sticky lets say , how can I make it in the bottom ? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here it explains how to do it https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination
and based on that you should do: 
1) In your controller change the line 
$content = content::all()->paginate(10);  
to be
$content = content::paginate(10);
2) In your view you could use this 

{{ $content->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}

This will do what you want!!